# Can't catch network error when using coroutine, but the error could be caught in RxJava 2. What did I miss?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code using Coroutine to perform network fetching on background

```
    try {
        networkJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val result = fetchOnBackground(searchText)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                showResult("Count is $result")
            }
        }
    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
        showResult(exception.localizedMessage)
    }
```

When the network is there, all is good. However, when either the host is not correct, or no network, it crashes. The `catch` can't catch it.

When I code using RxJava

```
    disposable = Single.just(searchText)
        .map{fetchOnBackground(it)}
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { showResult("Count is $it") },
            { showResult(it.localizedMessage) })
```

All works fine. Even in no network situation, the error is caught in the error callback.

What did I miss in the Coroutine code, that I can't catch the error on my end when using the Coroutine?

Note: the network fetching is using OkHttp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I need to put the `try-catch` within the `CouroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch`

```
    networkJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val result = fetchOnBackground(searchText)
            showResult("Count is $result")
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            showResult(exception.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
```

And I change my `showResult` to be a suspend function, so that it could include the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`

```
private suspend fun showResult(result: String) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // Code that show the result
    }
}
```